# Want to compress jpeg using blob with image as in and out parameter

Tags: java, oracle, blob, image-compression

i want to compress a jpeg Image, running a java program from an pl/sql procedure within th oracle database.

I want to call the java class from pl/sql procedure with the blob (jpeg image), an the java program should return the compresses image in a blob.
I have found this code from https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/desktop-java/imageio/compress-a-jpeg-file/ an it works fine and the jpeg images are compressed. But this program used jpeg-Files in the file system, i need the original image and the compresse image as blob parameter
I have used this program and have modified it to do what I need it to do.

To test my program, I get a jpg image from my database as blob via odbc an then call compressJPEG (myBlobCopy) with the blob. To show what happend, i do some output in the classes. The size of the blob before an after calling the compressJPEG is the same.

Here the output:
126 23190 myimage.jpg Length of retrieved Blob: 4284416
Length of copy Blob: 4284416
Call compressJPEG (myBlobCopy)
now in compressJPEG
Back from compressJPEG: Length of retrieved Blob: 4284416

Here the class. It seems, that the compressed image (blob) is not returned. Please can you help me!!!!!!

```
    import java.sql.*; 
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.image.RenderedImage;
import java.sql.Blob;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.util.Iterator;
import javax.imageio.IIOImage;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriteParam;
import javax.imageio.ImageWriter;
import javax.imageio.stream.ImageOutputStream;
//import java.sql.SQLException;     
class OracleConCompressBLOB{  
public static void main(String args[]){  
try{  
//step1 load the driver class  
 Blob myBlob = null;
 Blob myBlobCopy = null;

Class.forName("oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver");  
String dbURL = "jdbc:oracle:thin:@(DESCRIPTION = (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = xxxx)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME = xxxx) ) )";
String strUserID = "xxxx";
String strPassword = "xxxxx";
//step2 create  the connection object  

Connection con=DriverManager.getConnection(dbURL,strUserID,strPassword);
  

//step3 create the statement object  
Statement stmt=con.createStatement();  
  
//step4 execute query  
// fuer pbent   ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select PRFO_ID, PRFO_PRAX_ID , PRFO_DATEINAME, PRFO_FOTO from T_PRAFOTO where PRFO_ID = 17");
ResultSet rs=stmt.executeQuery("select PRFO_ID, PRFO_PRAX_ID , PRFO_DATEINAME, PRFO_FOTO from T_PRAFOTO where PRFO_ID = 166  FOR UPDATE");

  
   if (rs.next()) {
      myBlob = rs.getBlob(4);
      myBlobCopy = myBlob;
      System.out.println(rs.getInt(1)+"  "+rs.getInt(2)+"  "+rs.getString(3)+" Length of retrieved Blob: " + myBlob.length());  
      System.out.println(" Length of copy Blob: " + myBlobCopy.length());  
      System.out.println("Call compressJPEG (myBlobCopy) ");    
     compressJPEG (myBlobCopy)   ;           
    System.out.println("back from compressJPEG: Length of retrieved Blob: " + myBlobCopy.length());  
  }


//step5 close the connection object  
con.close();  
  
}catch(Exception e){ System.out.println(e);}  
  
}  


public static void compressJPEG(Blob blob) throws IOException {

//     File imageFile = new File("myimage.jpg");
//     File compressedImageFile = new File("myimage_compressed.jpg");

//     InputStream is = new FileInputStream(imageFile); 
//     OutputStream os = new FileOutputStream(compressed ImageFile);
    System.out.println("now in compressJPEG");  

   BufferedImage bufferedImage = null;
   OutputStream outputStream = null;
   float quality = 0.5f;
    try {
    // create a BufferedImage as the result of decoding the supplied InputStream
//    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(is);
    bufferedImage = ImageIO.read(blob.getBinaryStream()); 
    outputStream = blob.setBinaryStream(0); 
    // test
    // get all image writers for JPG format
    Iterator<ImageWriter> writers = ImageIO.getImageWritersByFormatName("jpg");

    if (!writers.hasNext())
        throw new IllegalStateException("No writers found");

    ImageWriter writer = (ImageWriter) writers.next();
    ImageOutputStream ios = ImageIO.createImageOutputStream(outputStream);
    
    writer.setOutput(ios);

    ImageWriteParam param = writer.getDefaultWriteParam();

    // compress to a given quality
    param.setCompressionMode(ImageWriteParam.MODE_EXPLICIT);
    param.setCompressionQuality(quality);

    // appends a complete image stream containing a single image and
    //associated stream and image metadata and thumbnails to the output
    writer.write(null, new IIOImage(bufferedImage, null, null), param);

    // close all streams
   // is.close();
  //  os.close();
  //  ios.close();
  //  writer.dispose();
                outputStream.flush();
                ios.close();
                outputStream.close();
               writer.dispose();      
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: Why don't you use the compression option on the BLOB column itself in the database?

Comment: I use the images in a pdf generator. sometimes this doesn´t work and the images will not show in the pdf. After compression the jpeg it works.
until now we used ordimage, to do the compression, but it is not longer supported from oracle in the newer version of the database.